# How to make a Multilanguage app

Tags: iphone, multilingual

I am doing a  IPhone multi-language app ,the problem is how can i change the app language at the case of not changing the system language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the global language setting in your user defaults by calling

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YOURCOUNTRY" forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

However by doing this your user will have to restart the application unless you call this in the `main()` method before `UIApplicationMain()` is called

Edit: look [here](http://blog.federicomestrone.com/2010/09/15/iphone-apps-and-device-language-setting/) for an example on how to do this.